# Remove duplicates objects from array by name and max category

Tags: javascript

How should I remove duplicate objects with the condition?

suppose I have this array :

```
let my_array = [
  { name: "foo", version: "10" },
  { name: "foo", version: "60" },
  { name: "foo", version: "20" },
  { name: "bar", version: "400" },
];
```

I need to keep the object that has latest version in it from duplicates.

I know I can use Set for removing dups :

```
let unique = my_array.filter((set => f =>
    !set.has(f.name) && set.add(f.name)
  )
  (new Set)
)
```

the expected result with condition of max version is :

```
let my_array = [
  { name: "foo", version: "60" },
  { name: "bar", version: "400" },
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @Liam no . I said I need to keep the object that has latest version in it from duplicate objects beside the rest of objects .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [object.Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to remove duplicates and get max `version` of each `name`.

**Demo**

```js
let my_array = [
  { name: "foo", version: "10" },
  { name: "foo", version: "60" },
  { name: "foo", version: "20" },
  { name: "bar", version: "400" },
];

let unique = Object.values(my_array.reduce((r, x) => {
  r[x.name] = r[x.name] && r[x.name].version > x.version ? r[x.name] : x
  return r
}, {}))

console.log(unique )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result by using `reduce`

```js
let my_array = [{
    name: "foo",
    version: "10"
  },
  {
    name: "foo",
    version: "60"
  },
  {
    name: "foo",
    version: "20"
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    version: "400"
  },
];

var new_array = my_array.reduce((max, b) => Math.max(max, b.version), my_array[0].version);

console.log(new_array)
```

Comment: check my question again .